# 2 Symfony routes with the same pattern, how to?

Tags: symfony, url, routes

I am stuck in one issue and cannot get out of it.

I have 2 urls that look the same but should route to different controllers.

1. **mysite.com/{alias}** => will take to mysite.com/contact ; mysite.com/about...etc
   Controller: AppBundle:Default:page.html.twig
2. **mysite.com/{alias}** => will to take a list of shops I have in my database. Examples: mysite.com/ebay ; mysite.com/apple...etc
   Controller: AppBundle:Shop:index.html.twig

How would you do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You write Controller: AppBundle:Default:page.html.twig but instead of an action I see a template. Also you should really use different actions for the /contact, /about etc. sites. Is there a specific reason why you want to use only one?

Comment: Yes, I have my old routing /ebay, /amazon...etc I must keep, otherwise I lose all my google ranking :)
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Using the same pattern is not a good idea, since Symfony will try to match all your routes one by one, in the order you defined in your routing.yml. So your second pattern will always be ignored when the first will be matched.

I advise you to be more accurate on your patterns: you should have exact patterns for your static pages (/contact, /about, etc.) and have a controller action for each. If you don't want, you can define several `@Route` annotation on a single action, or define `requirements` to a single `@Route` annotation. (like `@Route("/{alias}", requirements={"alias"="(contact|about)"}`)

Then, you can have a fallback pattern `/{alias}` for the list of shops.

**EDIT:**
The aim is, instead of having a single Regex to match all your cases, to have several of them, but with the same behaviour that you already have.

If you define routing this way (in this exact order):

```
1. /contact => Contact action
2. /about => About action
3. /{alias} => Shop action (matches every other URL than /contact and /about, like /amazon, /ebay, etc.)
```

Then this should work as you intend.

If the user visits **yoursite.com/contact**, the first pattern will match, thus the user will see the contact page.

If the user visits **yoursite.com/about**, the first pattern will fail but the second will match, thus the user will see the about page.

If the user visits **yoursite.com/ebay**, the first and second patterns will fail but the third will match, thus the user will see the shop page associated to the `"ebay"` slug.

Comment: Cheers. As I said on top, I need to keep these patterns because of the app old routing, otherwise I lose 50% of my google ranking.

I thought about the idea of @Route("/{alias}", requirements={"alias"="(contact|about)"}), but my app is in 8 different languages, so the llist of the requirements will be quite large. 
Only if there is a better way to tell the requirements={} to look for a translation file for the list. Do you know about anything like this?

Comment: It is not possible to internationalize the requirements as far as I know. About your Google Ranking, I did not mean your should change your URL patterns, I meant you should change how your patterns are defined in Routing. My solution is intended to keep your current URL schemas, while handling it better inside the Symfony framework. I will edit to add some clarification though.

Comment: By the way, how do you internationalize your routes right now? Could you paste us some code (like route definitions or controller actions)?

Comment: That looks fine, but my problem is the internationalisation. Which means, following your example, I will have something like:

/contact => Contact action (in 8 languages)
/about => Contact action (in 8 languages)

Comment: That's why I asked how you are handling internationalisation right now :) What are you using to handle different languages? On my own projects, I use JMSI18nRoutingBundle, that might do the trick for you.

Comment: Example:
/kontakt - for german, danish, polish, swedish
/yhteyshenkilö (dont laugh, finnish)
/contatto - for italian
/contacto - for spanish
/contact - for french

and the same for all other actions:
/about => About action (in 8 languages)
/user-agreement => UA action (in 8 languages)
...etc  
the list could be very long. And I guess this is a no go.

I havn't used JMSI18nRoutingBundle. I thought I could find an easier solution without installing a bundle :)

But it looks like there is nothing simple to handle my need, right?

Comment: In the long run you might need this bundle indeed. But in the short run, you can still define several `Route` annotations on the top of your contact action, one for each translation of `/contact`

Comment: what about "conditions"? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html
Can I have a condition in my routing annotation to do this task?

Comment: Never tried, can't help you more on this. If you use Conditions, be careful, the documentations states that "Conditions are not taken into account when generating a URL."